# pass filenames from bash command to postgres table

Tags: postgresql, amazon-s3

I want to get the list of my objects in an S3 bucket. I found this command which does the job perfectly

```
aws s3 ls s3://bucket_name/images --recursive | awk '{print $4}' > my_images.txt
```

this command output is

```
images/image1
images/image2
...
```

I am expecting over 12 million records to be fetched, is there a way to directly insert them into a table in PostgreSQL?

ideally, the output table would be

```
id,filename
1,image1
2,image2
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your output file is basically a CSV file. Pipe that to the PostgreSQL copy command.
You'll find all the options you need here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html